# How can I use Canvas upon/in/with Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter, canvas

I'm trying to draw a rectangle on the empty space, but every time I create something with Canvas, it moves all the buttons down (image 2). I don't want the buttons created with [Tkinter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tkinter) to move when I use Canvas. Is there a way I can do it?

[Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mYpFf.png)

[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tD77y.png)

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

colors = {
    0:"#ab91ff", 1:"#d0a176", 2:"#ecce86", 3:"#ecff91", 4:"#fff991", 5:"#92ff9f", 6:"#f991ff", 7:"#91dfff",
    8:"#d2ff91", 9:"#b8ff91"
}
buttonsPos = {
    "H":[1, 1, colors[0]], "He":[1, 18, colors[7]],

    "Li":[2, 1,  colors[1]], "Be":[2, 2, colors[2]], "B":[2, 13, colors[5]], "C":[2, 14, colors[0]], "N":[2, 15, colors[0]],
    "O":[2, 16, colors[0]], "F":[2, 17, colors[6]], "Ne":[2, 18, colors[7]],

    #more data...
}

DEFAULT_BOLD = ("Helvetica", "15", "bold")

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("900x414")
        self.root.iconbitmap("./icon.ico")
        self.root.title("Tabla periódica de los elementos")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.c = Canvas(self.root)
        self.c.pack()
        self.c.create_rectangle(50, 150, 250, 50, fill="pink")
        self.buttonsFrame = self.createFButtons()
        self.buttons = self.createButtons(self.buttonsFrame)


    def do(self):
        pass

    def createButtons(self, frame):
        bs = []
        for k,v in buttonsPos.items():
            b = Button(frame, command=partial(self.do, str(k)), text=str(k), font=DEFAULT_BOLD, height=1, width=3,
                       borderwidth=4, bg=v[2])
            b.grid(row=v[0], column=v[1], sticky=NSEW)
            bs.append(b)
        return bs

    def createFButtons(self):
        frame = Frame(self.root, bg="#ebebeb")
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
        return frame

    def loop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = GUI()
    c.loop()
```

Comment: what is the point of using a dictionary if you basically use indexes to access the values? the same effect could be achieved by using a list (I am talking about colors dictionary, there is no point to use that, just use a list or if you want to use a dictionary, have some color names instead of numbers so that it is understandable for people what color that hex code represents)

Comment: also I can't reproduce the issue from the given code, please provide a [mre]. I think you should add all the table data (or at least as much as is needed for reproducing the issue), otherwise I can't reproduce the issue, no matter how large is the rectangle, it doesn't move anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a canvas and a buttons frame. They are two different widgets and packed one after another. You can’t create any rectangle on top of the frame. So creating a rectangle in the canvas resizes the canvas widget that pushes the button's frame down.

You can create a canvas inside a button's frame and position using absolute positioning with the *place* command.

```
from tkinter import *
from functools import partial

colors = {
    0:"#ab91ff", 1:"#d0a176", 2:"#ecce86", 3:"#ecff91", 4:"#fff991", 5:"#92ff9f", 6:"#f991ff", 7:"#91dfff",
    8:"#d2ff91", 9:"#b8ff91"
}
buttonsPos = {
    "H":[1, 1, colors[0]], "He":[1, 18, colors[7]],

    "Li":[2, 1,  colors[1]], "Be":[2, 2, colors[2]], "B":[2, 13, colors[5]], "C":[2, 14, colors[0]], "N":[2, 15, colors[0]],
    "O":[2, 16, colors[0]], "F":[2, 17, colors[6]], "Ne":[2, 18, colors[7]],

    #more data...

}

DEFAULT_BOLD = ("Helvetica", "15", "bold")

class GUI():
    def __init__(self):
        self.root = Tk()
        self.root.geometry("900x414")
        self.root.title("Tabla periódica de los elementos")
        self.root.resizable(False, False)
        self.buttonsFrame = self.createFButtons()
        self.buttons = self.createButtons(self.buttonsFrame)

        self.c = Canvas(self.buttonsFrame, width=150, height=50)
        self.c.place(x=100, y=0)
        self.c.create_rectangle(0, 100, 150, 0, fill="pink")

    def do(self):
        pass

    def createButtons(self, frame):
        bs = []
        for k,v in buttonsPos.items():
            b = Button(frame, command=partial(self.do, str(k)), text=str(k), font=DEFAULT_BOLD, height=1, width=3,
                       borderwidth=4, bg=v[2])
            b.grid(row=v[0], column=v[1], sticky=NSEW)
            bs.append(b)
        return bs

    def createFButtons(self):
        frame = Frame(self.root, bg="#ebebeb")
        frame.pack(fill="both", expand="True")
        return frame

    def loop(self):
        self.root.mainloop()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    c = GUI()
    c.loop()
```

Comment: I would also suggest inheriting from `Tk` as to not create an attribute of `root` but instead use the instance (`self`)

Answer (score -1):

You can play with the `pack` arguments passed to `Canvas`:

```py
self.c = Canvas(self.root)
self.c.pack(...)
```

Another option would be using `grid` instead of `pack`, but you should modify the whole code (because `grid` and `pack` can't be together).

You can find useful information about Tkinter widgets here: *[Python GUI with Tkinter](https://coderslegacy.com/python/python-gui/)*. You can find a quick guide of `Canvas` here: *[Python Tkinter Canvas](https://coderslegacy.com/python/tkinter-canvas/)*.

Comment: so you actually won't answer the question? you give no clear or direct answer that would solve the OP's problem, just suggest some stuff and provided some documentation, besides that even won't solve the issue

Comment: Yes, I was reading my post again, and I want to apologize.

Comment: There is still time to [change your answer](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/69623192/edit). The old version will forever be in the revision history - ***there isn't any need to keep it and there isn't any need to use "Edit:", "Update:", or similar*** - the answer should appear as if it was written today). The "why" of the change should be in the edit summary or perhaps in comments here (*never* in the post itself).